Missing type-safety of MUI System sx
I would like the TypeScript compiler to catch typos in my MUI System sx props:
import { Box, SxProps, Theme, Typography } from '@mui/material'
    
const sxRoot: SxProps<Theme> = {
  width: '100vw',
  height: '100vh',
  diplay: 'grid', // <-- typo should lead to TS compile-time error
  placeItems: 'center',
}
    
export const App = () => (
  <Box sx={sxRoot}>
    <Typography>{'Hello World'}</Typography>
  </Box>
)

Please check out my example project based on the Vite react-ts template with MUI 5.15.19.
What am I missing?

Would you please check if the resource below helps you out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46291810/is-there-a-way-to-compile-or-detect-typos-in-javascript-node

display:"grid" is a valid SX prop. What do you mean by "typo should lead to TS compile-time error"

@AbouEmran it's diplay not diSplay

I just pulled your project and tested it, it seems that SxProps accepts that and is not very strictly typed as it allows a SystemStyleObject : type SystemStyleObjectand if you go deeper in the source code, you find the AllSystemCSSProperties which contains AliasesCSSProperties that allows you to add other css propersties that are not strictly css like bgcolor, mr, ml etcc.. which are understood by mui. I would recomeend using CssProperties as a type if you want to stricly pass css only. I Tested it on your project and typescript detects the error

Look at the screenshots one by one. The CSSSelectorObject interface has a index signature that means the key can be any string as can be seen in the screenshot, that's why you are not getting an error while passing incorrect key. This is a mistake maybe by MUI.





To catch typos in the MUI System sx props at compile-time using TypeScript, you need to enable strict type checking for the sx prop. By default, the sx prop allows any valid CSS properties, including unknown or misspelled properties.
Use the SystemStyleObject type from @mui/system instead of SxProps<Theme> to enable strict type checking. I put code snippets below that should fix your issue.
Update the sxRoot type to use SystemStyleObject:
import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { SystemStyleObject } from '@mui/system';

const sxRoot: SystemStyleObject = {
  width: '100vw',
  height: '100vh',
  diplay: 'grid', // <-- This will now lead to a TS compile-time error
  placeItems: 'center',
};

export const App = () => (
  <Box sx={sxRoot}>
    <Typography>{'Hello World'}</Typography>
  </Box>
);

By using SystemStyleObject, TypeScript will enforce strict typing for the sx prop and catch any misspelled or unknown properties at compile-time.
Also, (assuming you don't) make sure you have the necessary dependencies installed or this won't work.
npm install @mui/material @mui/system @emotion/react @emotion/styled

then just update the tsconfig.json file to use the settings:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}

